# Sifr browser issues

Tags: sifr

www.johncowle.co.uk/

I have employed Sifr on my site index. It works fine in Safari but nothing appears in Firefox.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you look at cufon (google it) if you want cross-browser based font replacement that doesn't require users to have flash

Comment: ive now found out sifr is only working in safari, not ie or firefox. if i could get it in ie id be very happy!